# RPI kiosk mode fullscreen epiphany

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, kiosk-mode, epiphany

I have a raspberry pi 2 model B with Raspbian that i want to boot into fullscreen browser.

I can get it boot into the browser with the right url, but not in fullscreen.

I am using ths command line to boot it up.

```
epiphany-browser http://mylink.com
```

What should i do to get it into fullscreen?

Comment: duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14454/26266

Answer (score 3):

install *xautomation* first:

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

and then you can put this in a shell script:

```
#/!/bin/bash

epiphany-browser http://mylink.com &
sleep 15
xte "key F11" -x:0
```

Got it from [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14459)